# Excel formula not working as expected

Tags: spreadsheet

I have a sheet that shows max values spent anywhere. So I need to find most expensive place and return it's name. Like this:

*Whole sheet.*
[image]

*Function.*
[image]

Function in text:

```
=IFS((A6=MAX(D2:D31)),(INDEX(C2:C31,MATCH(A6,D2:D31,0))),(A6=MAX(H2:H31)),(INDEX(G2:G31,MATCH(A6,H2:H31,0))),(A6=MAX(K2:K31)),(INDEX(K2:K31,MATCH(A6,L2:L31,0))))
```

Basically I need to find a word left to value, matching A6 cell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and does it have to be in that specific format? you know there is a lot easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. Overcomplicated!

Firstly, why the three rows? it's a lot easier if you just have one long row with all the data (tell me if you actually need 3 I'll change my solution)

```
=LOOKUP(MAX(D2:D31);D2:D31;C2:C31)
```

The MAX formula will lookup the biggest value in the list, the Lookup formula will then match it to the name.

[image: Spreadsheet]

Please note: If more than one object has the maximum price, it will only return the first one. The only way I can think of to bypass that would be to build a macro.

EDIT:

Alright.. Multi Column solution is ugly and requires extra columns that you can just hide.

[image]

As you can see you'll need 2 new columns that will find the highest for each row, 2 new columns that will find the value for each of these "highest" (in this case tree and blueberries) and then your visible answer will simply be an if statement finding out which one is bigger and giving the final verdict. This can be expanded with an infinite number of columns but increases complexity.

Here are the formulas:

```
MAX(H2:H31) 
LOOKUP(A5;H2:H31;G2:G31)    
MAX(L2:L31) 
LOOKUP(C5;L2:L6;K2:K6)  
IF(A5>C5;B5;D5)
```

Comment: Yes, I actually could do it with one column by myself :) I split it to make it more readable. And LOOKUP's can't handle this, so thats why so complicated :) Thanks for answer. Could you be so kind to change solution for (n) columns? Thank you!

Comment: @napoleoncake What do you mean "lookups can't handle this"?? You've been presented a solution, please explain why it's not suitable...

Comment: He meant lookups can't handle a multi column approach; Which is true. I've updated with a multi column solution as well.. Do note, it still does not solve the "2 numbers are identical and the biggest" problem. Still can't think of any solution other than a macro for that.